# Fresnel biprism little concepts

Tags: optics, refraction, interference

For a Fresnel biprism can anyone please tell how to prove that the distance between the virtual image sources formed is 2a(n-1)α . I can't find any resource where can I understand the derivation. Most resources say that angle of deviation of every Ray is δ=(n-1)α then do some geometry that i am unable to understand , and also why would every Ray deviate by δ isn't this the expression for minimum deviation so how is it used as such for every Ray.
Also i have a second question which is that the two virtual image of source S that would be formed due to refraction are on the plane of Source S , meaning why the two images and the source are collinear,is there any theoretical or logical justification or we just take it to be like that.[image]

Please help me in removing my doubt.

Comment: Please any help.

Answer (score 0):

Point Sources should have one horizontal ray coming out of them, so at the right hand side of the prism you have two horizontal rays after refraction.

applying Snell's law:
[image]
$\sin(\alpha+\theta) = n \sin(\alpha) $, using small angle approx.
$\alpha+\theta = n \alpha \tag{1}$
and $sin(\theta) = tan(\theta) = \theta = \frac{d/2}{a}$ substitute in eq.1 for $\theta$
$\alpha+ \frac{d/2}{a} = n \alpha \tag*{} \implies d = 2a\alpha(n-1)$